# Encoding request parameter in jmeter as json ->Gzip -> request parameter

Tags: gzip, jmeter, beanshell

Hi   I'm new to jmeter with bean shell script.

I want test my web service such that service only accept zipped json content. 
**(Accept: application/json
Content-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate)**

I have following queries:

1. How can I encode json request parameter as gzip using bean shell script?
2. Can we use any custom java class to encode (using bean shell's calling external java classes property) and bind with request ?

I simply want to do json ->Gzip -> request parameter in jmeter

Comment: Can anyone provide any useful links related to this topic?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding #2, so long as your JAR is in a known class path you should be able to use it with beanshell...however as I am sure you have seen, JMeter does not provide much feedback when it comes to debugging beanshell.